# Why are the coinfidence intervals predicted by arm::sim vs merTools::predictInterval different?

Tags: r, arm, multilevel-analysis

I'm comparing the [confidence-interval](/questions/tagged/confidence-interval) (`CI`)s produced by arm's `sim()` function and `predictInterval()` from `merTools`. 
I'm using the `sleepstudy` dataset from `lme4` as an example. 
I am expecting the same result from the two methods but that is not the case. What is the fundamental difference between the two methods what I am missing?

The code is the following:

## importing test data

```
sleepstudy <- as_tibble(sleepstudy) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(1:18, each = 10)) %>%
  dplyr::select(id, Days, Reaction) %>%
  filter(id <= 16)
```

## the multilevel model from lme4

```
lmerfit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | id), data = sleepstudy)
```

## generating prediction

This is to compare the median values generated later by *sim* and *preditInterval*.

```
sleepstudy$predicted <- predict(lmerfit, newdata=sleepstudy, allow.new.levels=T)
```

## CIs using arm: Individual level

```
sims <- sim(lmerfit, n.sims = 1000)
yhat <- fitted(sims, lmerfit)
sleepstudy$lower <- apply(yhat, 1, quantile, prob=0.025)
sleepstudy$median <- apply(yhat, 1, quantile, prob=0.5)
sleepstudy$upper <- apply(yhat, 1, quantile, prob=0.975)
```

## CIs using merTols

```
preds <- predictInterval(lmerfit, 
newdata = sleepstudy, 
n.sims = 1000, 
include.resid.var=FALSE, 
level=0.95, 
stat="median")
sleepstudy <- cbind(sleepstudy, preds)
```

As an example I am plotting the first data together with the two different CI prediction. Black points are the data. Red points are the predicted values from `lmerfit`. 
Black line and black dashed lines are the median and 95% CIs from `arm::sim` respectively.
Red line and dashed lines are the median and 95% CIs from `merTools::predictInterval` respectively.

The predicted values and simulated median values are identical, but the CIs are rather different. What could be the reason? Which one is accurate?

```
ggplot(data =  filter(sleepstudy, id == 1), aes(x=Days, y=Reaction)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(y=predicted), col = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=median), col ="black" ) +
  geom_line(aes(y=lower), col ="black", lty = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=upper), col ="black", lty = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit), col = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=lwr), col = "red", lty = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=upr), col = "red", lty = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The merTools CRAN page goes into this (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html), making a direct comparison between sim and predictInterval. Basically, my understanding is that sim ignores uncertainty about the random intercepts, using the mode as a point estimate. The intervals for predictInterval are wider because they account for this additional uncertainty, and are therefore probably more realistic.